# How to apply a fix on older version without losing new changes?

Tags: git

Me and my team are working on a service whose master's current version is 4.0.14 and 3.3.14 is the version which is in production currently.

We have to resolve log4j issue in production.

Changes after 3.3.14 are for new feature, initially we thought we will push log4j fix with new feature changes in production but it will take atleast 3 months more to get completed and we can't wait that much to apply a fix.

So now we have to apply the fix on version 3.3.14 and also not lose new feature changes.
I know this can be done using git reset and git revert.

I tried following approach using git reset on personal imported repo:

1. Take a master-copy branch from master.
2. Do hard reset on master to version 3.3.14 using force push.
3. Take a branch from reseted master, apply fix and merge into reseted master.
4. Deploy it to production.
5. Merge master-copy branch to master by resolving few conflicts since the code change for fix is   minimal.

This approach worked successfully but using git reset is not considered as good practice, so it is the last approach I would like to go with.

I also tried following approach using git revert:

1. Take a master-copy branch from master.
2. Revert commits in master one by one till the commit for version 3.3.14.
3. Take a branch from reverted master, apply fix and merge into reverted master.
4. Deploy it to production.
5. Merge master-copy branch to master by resolving few conflicts since the code change for fix is   minimal.

The problem is there are 640 commits after version 3.3.14 and I got stuck in 2nd step because the commits which I had to revert had lot of conflicts which makes this approach too time consuming and error prone.

Can anybody suggest me any other approach ? I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Using git reset and|or git revert is **Bad Ugly Thing (tm)** in work-style, which must be avoided and used only as last resort solution

Read docs about

- GitFlow;
- hotfix branches;
- merging branches

Preferred and clean way for your task will be (I'm too lazy to write ready to use Git-commands, thus describe only methodology here):

- Create log4j-hotfix branch from `3.3.14`
- Commit|debug code into it
- Merge log4j-hotfix into `production`
- Merge log4j-hotfix into `master`, resolving (possible) conflicts

Comment: Exactly what I would have said. :)